# Reactjs - setting inline styles correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to use Reactjs with a kendo splitter. The splitter has a style attribute like

```
style="height: 100%"
```

With Reactjs, if I have understood things correctly, this can be implemented using an inline style

```
var style = {
  height: 100
}
```

However, I am also using Dustin Getz [jsxutil](https://github.com/dustingetz/react-dynamic-form-kendo/tree/master/webapp) to in an attempt to split things a part a bit more and have independent html fragments. Thus far I have the following html fragment (splitter.html)

```
<div id="splitter" className="k-content">
  <div id="vertical">
    <div>
      <p>Outer splitter : top pane (resizable and collapsible)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="middlePane">
      {height}
      <div id="horizontal" style={height}>
        <div>
          <p>Inner splitter :: left pane</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Inner splitter :: center pane</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Inner splitter :: right pane</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
  <p>Outer splitter : bottom pane (non-resizable, non-collapsible)</p>
</div>
```

and a splitter.js component which references this html as follows

```
define(['react', 'external/react/js/jsxutil','text!internal/html/splitter.html'],
  function(React, jsxutil, splitterHtml) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('in app:' + splitterHtml);
    return React.createClass({

      render: function () {
        var scope = {
          height: 100
        };
        console.log('about to render:' + scope.height);

        var dom = jsxutil.exec(splitterHtml, scope);
        console.log('rendered:' + dom);
        return dom;
      }    
    });
  }
)
```

Now when I run this, I can see the height correctly if I put it as content. However, when it executes as the style properties I am getting an error

```
The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string.
```

So I obviously haven't quite got it mapped across correctly.

I'd be really grateful if someone could give me a steer on correcting this.

Comment: This sounds to me like a problem with jsxutil.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
var scope = {
     splitterStyle: {
         height: 100
     }
};
```

And then apply this styling to the required elements:

```
<div id="horizontal" style={splitterStyle}>
```

---

In your code you are doing this (which is incorrect):

```
<div id="horizontal" style={height}>
```

Where `height = 100`.

Answer (score 159):

You could also try setting `style` inline without using a variable, like so:

`style={{"height" : "100%"}}` or,

for multiple attributes: `style={{"height" : "100%", "width" : "50%"}}`

Comment: Is there a way to get around this for things that are not percentage based? For example: `WebkitAnimationIterationCount` ?

Comment: `style={{"height" : "30px", "width" : "30px"}}` you could write any css value. Its not restricted to percentage values.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy the docs state that numbers are automatically converted to px, but I came here trying to find how to set a percentage - so thanks to myuuf, very helpful.  The docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/style-props-value-px.html

Comment: Happy to help @MichaelStoner :)

Comment: for _dashed_ properties like `font-size` use camelcase `style={{"fontSize" : "30px"}}`.

Answer (score 15):

It's not immediately obvious from the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/style-props-value-px.html) why the following does not work:

```
<span style={font-size: 1.7} class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
```

But when doing it entirely inline:

- You need double curly brackets
- You don't need to put your values in quotes
- React will add some default if you omit `"em"`
- Remember to camelCase style names that have dashes in CSS - e.g. font-size becomes fontSize:
- `class` is `className`

The correct way looks like this:

```
<span style={{fontSize: 1.7 + "em"}} className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct and more clear way is :

```
<div style={{"font-size" : "10px", "height" : "100px", "width" : "100%"}}> 
    My inline Style
</div>
```

It is made more simple by following approach :

// JS

```
const styleObject = {
      "font-size" : "10px",
      "height" : "100px",
      "width" : "100%"
}
```

// HTML

```
<div style={styleObject}> My inline Style </div>
```

Inline `style` attribute expects object. Hence its written in `{}`, and it becomes double `{{}}` as one is for default react standards.