# Tag Error: React JSX Style Tag Error on Render

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my react render function

```
render:function(){
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="rr">something</p>
      <style>
        .rr{
          color:red;
        }
      </style>
    </div>    
  )
}
```

This gives me this error

> JSX: Error: Parse Error: Line 22: Unexpected token :

What's wrong here?
Can I embed full normal css into a react component?

Comment: A related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21534899/465053).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

JSX is only a small extension to javascript, it's not its own full blown templating language. So you would do it like in javascript:

```
return (
  <div>
    <p className="rr">something</p>

      <style>{"\
        .rr{\
          color:red;\
        }\
      "}</style>
  </div>
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6rqz068/

However there is absolutely no good reason to do this at all.

Comment: There are good reasons to do this, just not for the most common use-cases.

Comment: @oskarth can you elaborate?

Comment: @Esailija For instance in a CMS where you want to bring up a color admin that'll change CSS for a whole page "live". You'd have a dynamic <style> element listening to changes in a flux store, and in your admin you change the store data. Using inline styles instead would be slow and silly, especially if you'd use the same CSS later to create some static stylesheet file.

Comment: I can think of a good reason to do it... Defining CSS transitions when there is a variable length of something. If you just overwrite the "left" attribute you won't get the CSS transition, but if you rename a class you would. AFAIK

Comment: Also to define animations or media-queries. I can see this using in conjunction with the the proposed method by React.

Comment: Another good reason: `input::selected { color: ${this.props.color} }`

Comment: Another good reason: using React server side to render html strings for email templates. Lets you use all the power of React and your existing data and components to create nice emails. But this requires a style tag that you can run through an auto-inliner.

Comment: There are bajillions of good uses for this, like generating keyframe animations.

Comment: However there is absolutely no good reason to do this at all .... you haven't worked for the company I work for have you? you haven't had all their restrictions imposed on you have you?

Answer (score 133):

Easy to do with es6 template strings (which allows line breaks). In your render method:

```
const css = `
    .my-element {
        background-color: #f00;
    }
`

return (
    <div className="my-element">
        <style>{css}</style>
        some content
    </div>
)
```

As for use case I'm doing this for a div with some checkboxes that I'm using for debugging, that I would like to contain within one file for easy removal later.

Comment: Cleanest solution

Comment: Perfect Solution! Thanks

Comment: you can not have the `class` keyword in jsx

Comment: React will escape string `css`.
```
css = `.my-element {
    font-family: Georgia,Cambria,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    background-color: #f00;
`;
```
you will not get your facing backgroud color

Comment: @SeanPlusPlus thank you, I have updated the answer (8+ years after I wrote it lol)

Answer (score 30):

Inline-styles are best applied directly to the component JSX template:

```
return (
  <div>
    <p style={{color: "red"}}>something</p>
  </div>
);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/chantastic/69z2wepo/329/

---

**Note: JSX does not support HTML syntax for the style attribute**

Declare properties in using camelCase property names, e.g.,

```
{ color: "red", backgroundColor: "white" }
```

Further reading here: http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Comment: I think you are right.. :(   but it says it's support over at http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html

Comment: I'll remove that part from the answer.

Comment: Thanks, to give bigger problem I'm trying to solve is to have a react componenet that takes a css file, parses it and outputs it as part of a rendered component..    inline style won't work in this case

Comment: A solution to that particular problem is touched on in this talk by Christopher Chedeau, Facebook employee and React contributor. https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js

I believe they using Webpack loaders to accomplish this: http://webpack.github.io

Comment: webpack is awesome but that solves dependency management and isn't really the issue here.  Additional context - I'm trying to so this on the server side (hence taking a file reference as input), the renderToString method is what I intend to render ont he client.. but that needs to be able to handle normal css (example bootstrap) and embedded it.

Comment: That talk also speaks to that, the need to have some type of intermediate layer that can analyze CSS and change it to the js-object syntax that JSX expects. This would be impossible to solve without knowing your stack.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, why the need for inline, server-rendered styles? The benefit to the inline stylesheet seems mute if you're using an off-the-shelf css framework.

Comment: arg, looks like what I want isnt possible using react!  I'm going to take bootstrap, namepsace it and then load it onto the client.

Comment: Is there anything else needed to improve the answer to the originally posted question?

Comment: You can update you answer to be.. JSX style tag does not support the css syntax..  curious what it does though.

Comment: If it is at all helpful, http://topcoat.io is a CSS framework that is well namespace out of the box.

Comment: I want to add my own namespace. myapp-nav-bar  myapp-list-group-item ..etc

Comment: The answer has been updated to not that JSX does not support style-attribute syntax.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. It was not about inline styles.

Answer (score 20):

This can be done by using backtick "`" as below

```
return (<div>
        <p className="rr">something</p>


          <style>{`
            .rr{
              color:red;
            }
          `}</style>
  </div>)
```

Answer (score 10):

"class" is a reserved word in JavaScript. Instead use "className".

Also, you have to remember you're using JSX, not HTML. I don't believe jsx will parse your  tags. A better approach is to create an object with your styles then apply that as the style (see below).

```
var styles = {
  color:"red";
}

return (
  <div>
    <p style={styles}>something</p>
  </div>    
)
```

Comment: right (updated), but that's not the problem. The probem is the injecting vanilla css into a react js component.

Comment: Thanks, to give bigger problem I'm trying to solve is to have a react componenet that takes a css file, parses it and outputs it as part of a rendered component..    inline style won't work in this case

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. It was not about inline styles.

Comment: @CazumaNiiCavalcanti It did answer the original question (you know, the one that was asked in 2014). It doesn't answer the edited question.

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis Oh, ok. Sorry.

Comment: Very nice! I can re-use the styles in this case. And I can change them dynamically (on user input of a color or choices of font properties, for example).

Answer (score 8):

1. Create a function to handle inserting the style tag.
2. Add the CSS you want to a string variable.
3. Add the variable to the returned JSX inside of your `<style>` tag.

   ```
   renderPaypalButtonStyle() {
       let styleCode = "#braintree-paypal-button { margin: 0 auto; }"
       return (
           <style>{ styleCode }</style>
       )
   }
   ```

Comment: This is an elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
render(){
    var styleTagStringContent = 
    ".rr {"+
       "color:red"+
    "}";
    return (
      <style type="text/css">
        {styleTagStringContent}
      </style>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution after hit and trial.
Key is dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
Code is as follows:

```
    <script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister-with Progress.min.js"></script>
    import React from 'react'
    const style = ` <pie-chart class="nested" offset="top">
    <style>
    path {
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-width: 90;
     }
    [color1] {
    stroke: #BFBDB2;
    stroke-width: 50;
            }
    [color2] {
    stroke: #26BDD8;
    stroke-width: 60;
            }
    [color3] {
    stroke: #824BF1;
        }
    [part="path"]:not([y]) {
    stroke: #BFBDB2;
    stroke-width: 60;
    opacity: 0.4;
               }
    </style>
    <slice color1 size="100%" radius="200"><!--No label--></slice>
    <slice color1 size="88%" radius="200" y="65"><tspan> $size</tspan></slice>
    <slice color2 size="100%" radius="100"> </slice>
    <slice color2 size="40%" radius="100" y="165"><tspan> $size</tspan></slice>
    <slice color3 size="100%" radius="0"> </slice>
    <slice color3 size="10%" radius="0" y="265"><tspan> $size</tspan></slice>
    </pie-chart>`


     export default function Styles() {
     return (
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:style}}/>   
         )
         }
```

Comment: This is my example, you can add you style tag. You can also check how to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. It is only a solution, you should try a better approach if possible.

Answer (score -3):

```
import styled from 'styled-components;

return (
 <div>
  <Test>something</Test>
 </div>
)
```

Next Step:

```
const Test = styled.p`
  color: red
`;
```

Comment: OP asked for how to inject styles, not how to create a component using this library.