# How to use the <style> balise in React file

Tags: reactjs

For a Quick demo purpose, i need to get the actual `<style>` balise from a page that already exist.

I know that this is not something to do, it's only for a demo.

I have a huge `<style>` balise to integer into a react app. I just want to copy paste in and make as little change as possible.

I've seen that :

```
<style>
    {'\
       div{\
          background-color:red;\
       }\
    '}
</style>
```

from here : [React JSX Style Tag Error on Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530462/react-jsx-style-tag-error-on-render)
is working but this need to edit all line of my  balise and i don't 
have the time for that.

I also tried this : 
https://medium.learnreact.com/the-style-tag-and-react-24d6dd3ca974

But unfortunately it's not working :/

I'm looking for a quick solution where i only need to edit the beginning and the end of my `<style>` balise.

Thanks in advance to the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template literal.

```js
const CSS = `
div {
  background: purple;
  color: orange;
}
`;

const app = (
  <div>
    <style>{CSS}</style>
    Hello, world!
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah, I wasn't able to understand the issue. just got it after seeing your answer. :)

Comment: also, you may reference for template literal (OP might not know about this)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a non react project with its styles and you are making it react, but you want to keep the css. If that is the case, I recommend the following:

1 - get the original  tag, place it to a css file, and import it into your project's base html, this way you still have your styles whitout doing anything to react

2 - get the original  tag, place it into a css file, and import it using javascript/webpack

```
import styles from './styles.css'
```

3 - if you still want to place a style tag in react in a similar fashion, I recommend you placing all the style css using the character ` to define de string in the following way (ECMAScript 2015) (the character ` is not the same than ' and it lets you use several spaces and even variables inside. Defining a string like this is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Template_literals)):

```
render(){
    let myCss = `
       div{
          background-color:red;
       }
    `;

    return (<style>
        {myCss}
    </style>)
}
```

4 - using "styled components". They are designed to make it easier to use css in react. Although they are intented to style a component, you also can do acopy paste of a whole css style inside one of the components. So, as long as all your react elements are children of the specific styled component you are using, it will use those styles. So you can perfectly do the following:

```
const styled = require('styled-components'); // or import styled from "styled-components";

let Wrapper = styled.div`
   div{
      background-color:red;
   }
`;

class MyReactProject extends React.Component {
    /** your react code **/

    render(){
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                { /* your react code */ }
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
    /** your react code **/
}
```

using styled components you can do a quick fix for the moment, and it will be easy to do a full styled components migration in the future (you only have to transform each of the base tags of your react project into styled components)

[link to styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/)