# Changing height of div element by adding the number of items React.js

Tags: css, list, reactjs, styling

I'm making an application using React.js. I have a list of items. A list of item is editable.

I want to add a title element next to a list of items and a height of title element should be changed as the number of item is increased or decreased.

Image[image]

If the number of item is decreased to 3, the height of title element(Advice & FAQ) should be shorten. If it is increased to 5, the height should be widened.

How can I achieve this functionality? I tried to use inline styling but I failed..

`<div className="titleElement" style={height: this.state.questionItem.length * 20px }></div>`

index.js

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        questionItem
    };
}

createItem(item){
    this.state.questionItem.unshift({
        item : item,
    });
    this.setState({
        questionItem : this.state.questionItem
    });
}

findItem(item) {
    return this.state.questionItem.filter((element) => element.item === item)[0];
}

toggleComplete(item){
    let selectedItem = this.findItem(item);
    selectedItem.completed = !selectedItem.completed;
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
}

saveItem(oldItem, newItem) {
    let selectedItem = this.findItem(oldItem);
    selectedItem.item = newItem;
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
    console.log(this.state.questionItem)
}

deleteItem(item) {
    let index = this.state.questionItem.map(element => element.item).indexOf(item);
    this.state.questionItem.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ questionItem : this.state.questionItem });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="list">
    <div className="titleElement" style={height: this.state.questionItem.length * 20px }></div>
    <QuestionList questionItem={this.state.questionItem} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}  saveItem={this.saveItem.bind(this)} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete.bind(this)} />
    <CreateItem questionItem={this.state.questionItem} createItem={this.createItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>);
}
}
```

Comment: you don't need to change it via js, css should handle all this stuff.

Comment: check here https://codepen.io/jilykate/pen/aLZaKP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're doing too much work manually. You should look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and have CSS automatically handle the height resizing for you. The end result would be something like (have not tested this, just giving you a conceptual idea):

```
render() {
    return (
    <div className="list" style={{"display": "flex";}}>
        <div className="titleElement" style={{"flex": 1}}></div>
        <div style={{"flex": 5; "display": "flex"; "flex-direction": "column"}}>
            <QuestionList questionItem={this.state.questionItem} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}  saveItem={this.saveItem.bind(this)} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete.bind(this)} />
            <CreateItem questionItem={this.state.questionItem} createItem={this.createItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    </div>);
}
```

The outer `div` has `display: flex` set to enable flex box, then you can play with the `flex: 1` and `flex: 5` settings in the children `divs` to get the widths correct.

I would then add the wrapping `div` around `QuestionList` and `CreateItem` so that you can make those appear vertically / in columns (with the `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` styles).

Comment: I needed to rewrite inline styling such as ` style={{"display" : "flex"}} ` .  But it worked perfect. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad you got it to work. I'll edit the answer to include the quotes :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with user1370384 that you are doing a lot of work manually, and here is a post that discusses the correct way to do inline styles as objects [Reactjs - setting inline styles correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534899/reactjs-setting-inline-styles-correctly).

However, if you wanted to do your original approach, perhaps backticks aka ES6 Template Literals may be a solution like below. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
render() {
    return (
    <div className="list">
        <div className="titleElement" style={{'height': `${this.state.questionItem.length * 20}px` }}>

        </div>
        <QuestionList questionItem={this.state.questionItem} deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}  saveItem={this.saveItem.bind(this)} toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete.bind(this)} />
        <CreateItem questionItem={this.state.questionItem} createItem={this.createItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    );
}
```